# How can I write a cursive letter k in math?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, amsmath, calligraphy

Using `amsmath`, writing `$\ell$` produces a cursive lowercase letter l.  I would like to have a reasonably matching cursive lowercase letter k, available through `\kay` e.g., so that I can write things like `$\kay,\ell \in S$`.

Is this possible?

Comment: `\ell` is not cursive. It has a loop to help diferentiate over other letters or symbols in math that may cause confusion. What you need is look for a font (probably script font) that has lowercase letters.

Comment: Related/duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211462/importing-single-symbols-in-the-sense-of-how-does-the-assignment-work

Answer (score 5):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Math}
\def\kay{\ensuremath{\mscrk}}
\begin{document}
 $\ell$ and $\kay$ and $\mscrl$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are happy to use the Stix fonts, you could try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
A script k in maths $\mathscr k$
\end{document}
```

Otherwise you need to find a maths font that implements the Unicode character: 
or "MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL K"
which is Unicode code point U+1D4C0, and compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.